# Monotone Convergence theorem for monotone decreasing sequences

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Short question: (Just an example. I want to know if similar thoughts can be used for other sequences of functions)

If I want to evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{[0,1]}-nxdx$, I can't do that with the monotone convergence theorem, since $f_n(x)=-nx$ isn't monotone increasing, but it is monotone decreasing.

But if I write instead $-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{[0,1]}nxdx$ the integrand is now monotone increasing. So I must be able to use the Monotone Convergence theorem here, right?

Can I use always this method for monotone decreasing sequences of functions?

Then why the Monotone Convergence theorem is only stated for increasing sequences of functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't always do that for decreasing sequences. MCT applies to increasing sequences of *positive* functions. Hence a decreasing sequence of negative functions is ok. Decreasing sequence of positive (or neither) functions, no.

Consider $f_n = \chi_{[n,\infty)}$ on the line. Or if you want a finite measure, consider $\frac1t\chi_{(0,1/n)}$ on $[0,1]$.